# Does nohup work as long as the server is running?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I recently decided to migrate my programs from AWS to a local server (Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running Raspbian). I SSH into the now local server where I send the following command (and please correct me if I'm wrong).

```
nohup ./Eye.sh & nohup ./Hand.sh & nohup ./Foot.sh &
```

The program does nothing over the weekend (and it is current 2AM on Sunday here) and will not start performing its task until 9:30AM on Monday. I need to know that I will not, hopefully ever, have to SSH back into the server to re-execute the commands, as it is crucial that the programs are running at all times.

Do I have anything to worry about? Will the program run as long as there is power to the system?

Comment: This seems somewhat like an **XY Problem**. See: [**What is the XY problem?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What are you trying to accomplish? Running with `nohup` simply runs each script in a manner that is immune to `hangup`. Much will depend on the scripts themselves -- it is difficult, without more, to see what advantage you expect from running the scripts with `nohup`. Why not just write the `PID` of each running script to a `pidfile` and verify the process is/remains running?

Comment: Another alternative is to simply set a `crontab` to run at 9:30  every Monday.

Comment: I'm going to have to do a little more research. The programs are written in Python and all have a `while` loop that needs to run continuously which is why I have written the `.sh` files (if the program fails, execute it again). If you think you have an answer please post it, otherwise I will be looking into the XY problem.

Comment: Without seeing the scripts, I'm not in a position to answer, but if I were in your shoes, I would either have the scripts write their PID to a pidfile in say `/var/tmp` and then a separate script that checks for each pidfile and confirms each process is running or restarts each as required -- or -- I'd just call each in a crontab when I needed them to run. I think you have explained the need -- just to insure they are continually running. You should search this site for restarting a script if not running -- there are several good schemes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As long as the server is running, you can close out of your SSH connection and your program will continue to run with the `nohup` command. If your server reboots, for whatever reason, you should consider using respawn.